# How to set merge multi level column in pandas which does display column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
df =
          name     age     character
0          A        10       fire
1          A        15       water
2          A        20       earth
3          A        25       air
4          B        10       fire
5          B        7        air
```

I organized it with groupby,

```py
df = df.groupby('name').aggregate(list)
```

then I have this output

```
        age          character
name
---------------------------------------
A     [10,15,20,25]   [fire, water, earth, air]
B     [10, 7]         [fire, air]
```

I tried to pivot this dataframe, based on `name` column. But after groupby, `name` columns is not in the columns anymore

```py
print(df.columns)
>>> ["age", "character"]
```

How can I lift up this column, so that I can use for pivot? 
**EDIT**
Expected output is,

```
name      age          character
---------------------------------------
A     [10,15,20,25]   [fire, water, earth, air]
B     [10, 7]         [fire, air]
```

Comment: Could you show the expected result?

Comment: `df = df.groupby('name', as_index = False).aggregate(list)`

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

However, pivoting list data is usually unhelpful.